# Why Profile php doesn't work? after logging in it doesn't show info like username and etc,

Tags: php, session

Why can'user information doesn't appear? do i need to specify something in login.php?
       please help

```
  <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
   ini_set('display_errors',1); 
  session_start();
  $username=$_SESSION['username'];
  $qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 $login_session=$row['username'];
 $facebook=$row['facebook'];
  $name=$row['name'];
  $email=$row['email'];
   ?>
   <p><?php echo $facebook ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $username ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $email ?></p>
   <p><?php echo $password ?></p>
```

and here is my login php Below I think there's problem with Session starting

```
    <?php
  session_start();
 error_reporting(E_ALL); // check all type of error
 ini_set('display_errors',1); // display those errors
 require 'db.php' ;
  if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){ // check  with posetd value
   $user_name = $_POST['username'];
   $password = md5($_POST['password']);
   $query = "SELECT * FROM users where username='$user_name' and password =    '$password'"; // don't use plain password, use password hashing mechanism
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$query); // run the query
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){ // if data comes

    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    header('location:profile.php'); // go to other page
    }else{
    echo "Login creadentials are not correct"; // else no user is there with                     the given credentials
   }

    }
   ?>
 <?php
  include 'Session.php';

  ?>
End of code here
```

Comment: depends on where/how `$_SESSION['username']` was assigned/set.

Comment: This page outputs nothing or other pages output nothing?

Comment: i did Something Like This,made Profile.php and Session.php i include this Session php but doesn't show anything doesn't even show Notices it just says 
username:
email:
facebook:
no errors but doesn't show anything either 
i start session after user logins

Comment: after user logins $_SESSIOn['username']=$username

Comment: you also didn't do anything with `$login_session`

Comment: your code works, far as I'm concerned and something is failing you.

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION['username']);` - `var_dump($username);` what do those show you? again; you didn't do anything with the `$login_session` variable here.

Comment: So this page works fine or this page displays nothing? You are not setting any `$_SESSION`s here so no other page can get this data..

Comment: [which is what I told them from the get go......](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635964/why-profile-php-doesnt-work-after-logging-in-it-doesnt-show-info-like-usernam#comment70471553_41635964) @chris85 ;-)

Comment: and view your HTML source; what does that show you besides what I already asked?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, that bit could work though, all other queried values won't be saved though. I think we've already lost the OP though..

Comment: @chris85 I tested their code and using `$_SESSION['username'] = "John";` - so I know that works and got back everything. OP isn't answering to my comments, unless they feel overwhelmed or don't know what to do.

Comment: `mysqli_error($con)` on the query throws back what? you need to answer all my comments if you want me to continue helping. Otherwise, stick to the answer given below. Again; your code works.

Comment: @Fred-ii- -ii-okay bro i will answer just give me a sec

Comment: @Fred-ii- bro var-dump says NULL

Comment: And None of Errors Appear,As i said earlier i'm sure in login i made session start but as i said It doesn't start because none of functions of session work anywhere

Comment: your session is empty / not set then.

Comment: @Fred-ii- bro i just edited my Question check it please

Comment: @GiorgiMacharashvili I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this: (look at the variables in `^^^^^^^^^`).

```
$user_name = $_POST['username'];
^^^^^^^^^^ 
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM users where ... '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query); // run the query
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){ // if data comes

$_SESSION['username']=$username;
                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

You assigned the `$user_name` variable to the `$_POST['username']` array, yet you assigned the `$_SESSION['username']` session array to the `$username` variable.

That should have read as:

```
$_SESSION['username']=$user_name;
```

What you should have done was to check if the session was set/not empty in an `if/else` conditional statement.

Make sure that the form does have the same name attribute for the POST array.

Note:

You should add an `exit;` after the header:

```
header('location:profile.php');
exit;
```

Otherwise, your code may want to continue executing below it.

---

Additional notes.

Your code is open to an SQL injection; please use a prepared statement:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

You should also look into hashing passwords safely using `password_hash()` instead of MD5 since that function is no longer considered safe to use in this day and age:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Note: If and when you do decide to switch to `password_hash()`, make sure the (password) column is long enough to hold the hash, 60+ / or better; 255.

Comment: @GiorgiMacharashvili I'm glad to hear it and you're very much welcome.

Comment: aaaah,I got It maaan Thnx For Explaining Nice broo

Comment: @GiorgiMacharashvili On an added note: You may want to create a logout link/page that will destroy the session http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php otherwise, it may result in unexpected behaviour and still hold a session array's value on the server. Reload my answer also, I made a few more additions to it.

Comment: Thanks Man For Notes! if i can somehow commend you Please Tell me and i will,I really Appreciate People like you Who Love helping beginners!

Comment: @GiorgiMacharashvili No worries; just telling them that you've been treated well is good enough ;-)

Comment: Okay Bro,Thanks a Lot ! Good Night sir,in my country it's night so :D and Wish you The Best meight!

Comment: @GiorgiMacharashvili Spain/Italy? prego... grazie, e buona notte ;-)

Comment: I'm From Georgia Bro,it's a little Country

Comment: @GiorgiMacharashvili Oh... ok. I know where you are. I thought you might have been Italian, kind of looked like it ;-) take it easy.